# Obtain data of Freight Index in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the data from this website, https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi , for China and Shanghai Continerized Freight Index.

I understand that the data is called from an API, how do I find out how the call is made and how do I extract it using python?

I am new in html in general so I have no idea where to start.

I tried,

```
import requests

url = "https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi"

resp = requests.get(url)
resp = resp.json()
```

But the response is `<Response [404]>`

If I change the url to  `https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/947/`
the response is `{'success': 0, 'data': [], 'msg': 'error #644'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 9633cefba71a598adae0fde0b56878fe',
    'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=n74gv10hc8po7mrj491rk4sgo1; _ga=GA1.2.1231997091.1631627585; _gid=GA1.2.1656837390.1631627585; _gat=1; _hjid=c52244fd-b912-4d53-b0e3-3f11f430b51c; _hjFirstSeen=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0'}

r = requests.get('https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/947', headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

output

```
{'success': 1, 'data': {' ...}
```

Comment: The Bearer Token or php session id probably won't consistently work

Comment: I agree - it should be obtained from time to time. (good point)

Comment: doesn't work, How can I obtain this parameters?

Comment: In the browser do F12 -> Network -> XHR and see the value of `Authorization` request header. Use it in the code,